# Cost of running a blockchain network

Tags: blockchain

Since this is a peer to peer and does not require expensive computers, what are the actual cost of running a blockchain network? It is a self managed network isn't it? Does it need a team of people managing it like database administrator, engineers...etc.

Not considering the cost of promoting the blockchain. Simply the setting up, maintaining and running the blockchain network.

Answer (score 0):

There are many types of blockchain networks. The decentralized networks like Bitcoin run only on user's computers, so there is no Central server to manage. It is just the user's up front cost for hardware and ongoing electricity and hardware maintenance of the computer hardware fails.

Federated and centralized networks might require these services, however, but blockchain solves the distributed consensus problem and is not required for centralized services since consensus can be determined easily.